# Rails get client's name of pc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do some integration with other app. I need client name of pc to login into app. I can take IP (request.remote_ip). How I can get name of pc?

Comment: What about this?

    require "socket";
    Socket.gethostname

Comment: Resolv.getname(request.remote_ip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

es There is many solution

1)   `require 'socket'`
   `Socket.gethostname`

2)  `system("hostname")`

3) If you want to get request host then `request.host`

If you want remote hostname

4) `require 'resolv'`
  `Resolv.getname(request.remote_ip)`

Thanks

Comment: I think he wants the remote hostname.

Comment: Posted also remote hostname